# Getting ReferenceError: openai is not defined, using puppeteer when making an API call to OpenAI

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, puppeteer, openai-api

Full Error: ReferenceError: openai is not defined

Issue calling openai API within puppeteer method 'evaluate'.

I'm having trouble identifying the error as to why the variable 'openai' is undefined at within the local scope of the calling function (line 24). I have attempted a multitude of solutions like relocating the declaration of variables 'configuration' and 'openai' within the local scope of the function using the variables, however, I keep receiving a non defined reference error.

**Code**

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { Browser } from 'puppeteer';
import { Configuration } from 'openai';
import { OpenAIApi } from 'openai/dist/api';

const fs = require('fs');

const url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/';

const main = async () => {

  const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_SECRET_KEY,
  })

  const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

  const browser: Browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const url = `https://www.youtube.com/${"@t3dotgg"}/videos`
  await page.goto(url)

  const videos = await page.evaluate(async (url) => {


    const videoObject = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#contents.style-scope.ytd-rich-grid-row"))
    const data = videoObject.map((video: any) => ({
      title: video.querySelector("h3 a").getAttribute("title"),

    }))

    const titles = data.slice(0, 10)

    const prompt = `The following is a list of youtube video titles. After reading the titles, you are given a topic to then write a similar title for. \n\TITLES: ${titles.map((object) => object.title)
        .join('\n')
      }\n\nSIMILAR TITLE FOR TOPIC "${"Christmas Coding"}"`

    const res = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt,
      temperature: 1,
      max_tokens: 256,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0,
      presence_penalty: 0,
    })

    return res.data.choices[0]!.text

  }, url, openai, configuration)

  console.log(videos)

  await browser.close();
  fs.writeFile('bookData.json', JSON.stringify(videos), (error: any) => {
    if (error) throw error
    console.log('Data written to file!')
  })
}

main();
```

Comment: Did you try `await page.evaluate((url, openai, configuration) => {`? That said, I sort of doubt that object can be serialized and work inside the browser--it's a Node thing. What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: Ah, I figured out the error, it was because as you said I couldn't serialize an object within the browser. So, I placed the api call outside of the browser scope. However, now I'm receiving a 429 error (too many requests made). Although, thank you for your comment as it lead to me fixing the error from the OP!